# Problems with reverse DNS pointing to unknown hostname

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver, reverse-dns

I am trying to create nameservers in my new OpenVZ VPS. It is a box running debian and I have installed webmin.

When I check if the primary nameserver is working I get the following message:

> Reverse for xx.10.xxx.11 points to an unknown host name (xx.10.xxx.11.customer.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com).

I can't find any PTR records that point to customer.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com

In the master zone I have created there are no PTR records, so where does this information come from?

If I check is the **/etc/bind/named.conf** file:

```
zone "localhost" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.local";
};

zone "127.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.127";
};

zone "0.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.0";
};

zone "255.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.255";
};

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
```

Why are there so many master zones? Are they needed?

Content of **/etc/bind/named.conf.local**

```
zone "XXXXXX.net" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/XXXXXXX.net.hosts";
    };
```

Are there any other places where information is stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your the address is resolving to your ISP. Unless you "own" that address you will need to ask the service provider to set up the reverse DNS for you.

Comment: Ah I see. Yes that was the problem. The reverse dns is done in the control panel of my ISP. Thank you